# wpf tabcontrol: Change content of generic tab based on selected tab

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs, tabcontrol

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
  <tabs:tab1/>
  <tabs:tab2/>
</TabControl>
```

tab1.xaml:

```
<usercontrol:GenericTab >
</usercontrol:GenericTab>
```

GenericTab.xaml:

```
<Button Name="btn_Button" Content="{Binding ButtonText, Mode=OneWay }" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" ></Button>
```

How to achieve following behavior:
If tab1 is selected in MainWindow, GenericTab.Button-Content should be for example "hello tab1" and if tab2 is selected, Generictab.Button-Content should be "hello tab2" ?

Comment: TabControl.SelectTab https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c881zk4f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How does this provide to the Answer? You apparently did not even read the question

Comment: Are "tab1" and "tab2" UserControls or what are these?

Comment: I see. Sorry for that.

Comment: No, tab1 and tab2 are TabItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the Tag property of the TabItem and then bind the Button's Content property to this one.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
    <TabItem Header="Tab1" Tag="hello tab1">
        <usercontrol:GenericTab />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2" Tag="hello tab2">
        <usercontrol:GenericTab />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**GenericTab.xaml:**

```
<Button Name="btn_Button" Content="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" ></Button>
```

Comment: For some reason, the FIRST tab lets the Content be empty - afterwards every Tab fills the content with the right text... I try to find out, whats the matter of the first not working. Anyways, thank you very much!!

Comment: Try to change the binding to:  Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}, Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: I think I see the problem now, the Binding does not see the first Tab as TabItem, but as TabControl. But it´s not. With the "new" approach, the content remains empty in all cases

Comment: Binding to the Tag property of the SelectedItem of the *TabControl* should work. It does for me :)